# WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403 in Ansbile

Tags: python, ansible, winrm

I installed Python3.11.6 for a specific need as a root user in Ansible on RHEL7 but then removed it by deleting the directories in usr/local/lib/python3.11 and
/usr/local/include/python3.11.

After this, Ansible, WinRM with HTTP and Kerberos which was working fine before the installation of Python3.11, stopped working and always throws error as below.

````
calling kinit with subprocess for principal serviceaccount@domain.com
kinit succeeded for principal serviceaccount@domain.com
<TargetHost001.domain.com> WINRM CONNECT: transport=kerberos endpoint=http://TargetHost001.domain.com:5985/wsman
<TargetHost001.domain.com> WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 248, in send_message
    root = ET.fromstring(ex.response_text)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: mismatched tag: line 118, column 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 426, in _winrm_connect
    self.shell_id = protocol.open_shell(codepage=65001)  # UTF-8
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 166, in open_shell
    res = self.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(req))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 251, in send_message
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 243, in send_message
    resp = self.transport.send_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 309, in send_message
    self.build_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 292, in build_session
    self.setup_encryption()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 298, in setup_encryption
    self._send_message_request(prepared_request, '')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/transport.py", line 338, in _send_message_request
    raise WinRMTransportError('http', ex.response.status_code, response_text)
winrm.exceptions.WinRMTransportError: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403
TargetHost001.domain.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 403",
    "unreachable": true
}```
I checked all the packages such as pywinrm, requests-ntlm, requests-kerberos and kerberos configuration. The Ansible with winrm was working fine for the last year till yesterday where I installed Python3.11 and removed those directories as stated above. 
Please help me on what might have broken this Ansible with WinRM.
````